# Select the rows from a Google Spreadsheet where values in a certain column are not empty using Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dataset and here is the link for that:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QgR7WC2bj2_AW7yTDnjEXDrYKGo1GR_w_ea-8PtRwm4/edit?usp=sharing

So what I want is,if any cell in column A has a date (not empty), I want to fetch the entire row.

I even got one script in stack overflow which is:

```
  function copynotempty(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0])
  var col = 0 ; // choose the column you want to check: 0 = col A, 1= col B ...
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var values=range.getValues();// data is a 2D array, index0 = col A
  var formulas=range.getFormulas();// data is a 2D array, index0 = col A
  var target=new Array();// this is a new array to collect data
   for(n=0;n<range.getHeight();++n){
     if (values[n][col]!=''){ ; 
                for (cc=0;cc<range.getWidth();++cc){
                if (values[n][cc]!=''){target[n][cc]=values[n][cc]}
    // if the cell has a formula copy it or else copy the value, do that for the whole row
// (this also defines and apply the 'priority' you mentioned in your question, I wasn't sure if it should apply to the whole row or only on column B)
                }
              }
            }
            if(target.length>0){// if there is something to copy
          var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]); //second sheet of your spreadsheet
          sh2.getRange(1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues();// paste the selected values in the 2cond sheet
          }
        }
```

but if i use this to the dataset that I have shared I am getting this error "TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "invited". (line 12, file "Code")".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following script? This script retrieves only rows that column A has strings.

Although you say that you want to retrieve rows by a condition of column B, your script watches column A as the condition. So if you use this sample script, please change "col". Now "col" is column A.

Script:

```
function copynotempty() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
  range.setNumberFormat('@');
  var values = range.getValues();
  col = 0;
  var target = values.filter(function(e, i){return (isNaN(e[col]) && i > 0)});
  ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target);
}
```

Result: This is imported to sheet2.

```
[[22/1/16, 2/2/16, 3/2/16, 3/2/16, 6/2/16],
[13/1/16, 13/1/16, 13/1/16, 13/1/16, 20/1/16],
[2/2/16, 2/2/16, 2/2/16, 2/2/16, 9/2/16],
[1/2/16, 1/2/16, 8/3/16, 14/3/16, 2/5/16],
[11/1/16, 11/1/16, 11/1/16, , ],
[12/2/16, 12/2/16, 12/2/16, 12/2/16, 20/2/16],
[28/1/16, 28/1/16, 28/1/16, , ],
[6/1/16, 6/1/16, 6/1/16, 6/1/16, 15/1/16],
[25/1/16, 25/1/16, 25/1/16, 25/1/16, 13/2/16],
[30/1/16, 3/2/16, 10/2/16, 10/2/16, 14/2/16],
[27/1/16, 27/1/16, 27/1/16, 27/1/16, 8/2/16],
[15/1/16, 23/1/16, 23/1/16, 23/1/16, 29/1/16],
[12/1/16, 12/1/16, 12/1/16, 12/1/16, 16/1/16],
[2/2/16, 3/2/16, 3/2/16, 3/2/16, 6/2/16],
[18/12/15, 5/1/16, 5/1/16, 5/1/16, 12/1/16]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the script. But for example if I have the dataset in sheet1 and if I try to use the script by writing "=copynotempty(Sheet1!A:E)" in sheet2 which is empty its throwing an error "You do not have permission to call setNumberFormat (line 4)." do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Updated the sample script. It imports the result to sheet2.

Comment: Thank you, too. Can you push the accept button to your this question?