# How to query Google Sheets by a column's value through Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is what my spreadsheet looks like - (In reality, it would have more than 10,000 rows)

[image: sample sheet]

The `For Class` column is my kind-of **main** column, and as you can see it can also have multiple appearances of a particular value (like `rows #3, #5, #8 & #10` have class = `7`). By using the Google Sheets API (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) I have till now managed to get the whole data (I set the range to just `Sheet1` & majorDimension to `ROWS`, and in result it returned me all my ~10,000 rows).

But what I am aiming to do is, just get all rows that have a specific `For Class` value (let's say, 7.) For example, if I were to run that command on my above sample snippet (with the `For Class` query value set to `7`), I would get the rows `3, 5, 8 & 10`. Is there any way I can achieve this through API?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

---

**P.S.** I have tried creating another sheet, adding a formula to it, so it would give me my desired result of all rows with `class = 7`. - It works, but I might have 100s of users accessing this sheet at any given time, & they would have different values to query with. So, creating a new sheet for filtered results isn't suitable for me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the rows from a Google Spreadsheet where values in a certain column are not empty using Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013579/select-the-rows-from-a-google-spreadsheet-where-values-in-a-certain-column-are-n)

Comment: Thanks, but I have found an idea, that I would retrieve all the data, and then filter it out later in my code.

Comment: Can you share it as an answer so more people can benefit from it?

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs, correct approach is

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(DATA_SOURCE_URL);
query.setQuery('select dept, sum(salary) group by dept');
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
```

References:

1. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage
2. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en&ref_topic=9054531